# india relating corporate law employment in government company harassment for not getting involved in irregular practices

Tags: india, government-contracts

Is it legal for a government-owned company in India to register vendors without publicity, and carry out a limited tender among them without publicity,by selecting among vendors registered on basis of arbitrary recommendation by company officials, in any state of India? Does this violate norms of Contract Law, or anti-corruption provisions? This goes against common sense and fairness.

In this case, vendors are registered without advertised invitation for enlistment in any newspaper or website and limited tender/NIT/Request for Quotation is carried out without any publicity. Is this legal as per relevant provisions of applicable laws of India?

This is has been going on for 6 years. An employee, on probation, refused get involved in this business process when he was asked do an inspection of approximately 23,000 rupees worth of material (printer paper reams), which he could not find, so he refused to sign off the inspection. As a result, a letter of caution was issued.

One month later, he was asked to do an inspection on basis of a purchase order, where the signature in place GM seal there was a signature of DGM but there was no mention that he was officiating as GM. Moreover the document had factual and technical errors regarding description of material so he verbally conveyed his inability and answered in writing to the letter of caution, mentioning that he has been asked from time to time sign incomplete and irregular documents, for which the DGM and Senior Manager verbally said that they will take revenge; and confirmation letter was not given but but appointment he auto-confirmed since probation was not extended but 3 increments have not been given without any letter, causing huge loss. What should the employee do, when many people know about this but are not doing anything, just verbally labeling as inefficient and arrears may be given but without loss compensation?

**What should be done by an employee to safeguard his employment and career interests, when there is a concerted effort to cover up possible corruption, and retaliation is happening against the employee for not contributing?**

Comment: Hi, Stacklooker. Welcome to the Law StackExchange. Feel free to take the tour: https://law.stackexchange.com/tour. I've edited your question to make it more readable. I have tried to keep your intentions constant through my edit. You can see what changes  I've made by clicking "edited" above my username, to the left of yours. If you do not like the changes I have made, please feel free to roll them back.

Comment: He should get a lawyer, quit the job, and wherever possible get out of the country where such a culture can develop largely unhindered.

Comment: @Nij, I presume you'd advise such an individual to colonize the Moon, then?

Comment: You don't need to live on the moon to avoid significant government corruption. Quite a few countries manage it successfully. Perhaps your experience has only ever been in places that haven't, and for that I pity you.

Comment: Please give a concrete answer solution within constraints